# Apache Beam Stateful DoFn Periodically Output All K/V Pairs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I'm trying to aggregate (per key) a streaming data source in Apache Beam (via Scio) using a stateful DoFn (using `@ProcessElement` with `@StateId` `ValueState` elements). I thought this would be most appropriate for the problem I'm trying to solve. The requirements are:

- for a given key, records are aggregated (essentially summed) across all time - *I don't care about previously computed aggregates, just the most recent*
- keys may be *evicted* from the state (`state.clear()`) based on certain conditions that I control
- Every 5 minutes, *regardless if any new keys were seen*, all keys *that haven't been evicted from the state* should be outputted

Given that this is a streaming pipeline and will be running indefinitely, using a `combinePerKey` over a global window with accumulating fired panes seems like it will continue to increase its memory footprint and the amount of data it needs to run over time, so I'd like to avoid it. Additionally, when testing this out, (maybe as expected) it simply appends the newly computed aggregates to the output along with the historical input, rather than using the latest value for each key.

My thought was that using a StatefulDoFn would simply allow me to output all of the global state up until now(), but it seems this isn't a trivial solution. I've seen hintings at using timers to artificially execute callbacks for this, as well as potentially using a slowly growing side input map ([How to solve Duplicate values exception when I create PCollectionView<Map<String,String>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54422510/how-to-solve-duplicate-values-exception-when-i-create-pcollectionviewmapstring)) and somehow flushing this, but this would essentially require iterating over all values in the map rather than joining on it.

I feel like I might be overlooking something simple to get this working. I'm relatively new to many concepts of windowing and timers in Beam, looking for any advice on how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try to help with an answer to this by tomorrow!

Comment: I suspect that the windowing / triggering options may be messing with your solution. You don't need the upstream trigger if you're setting timers to control your output rate. Can you try removing the upstream trigger?

Comment: Thank you @Pablo, that did seem to help. I'm able to see that keys are outputted every 5 minutes now, and they are triggered via timers when not present in new records! Any idea why i'd see the same key twice in the output for a given window though? I thought the TimestampCombiner.LATEST would fix this?

Comment: so windowing/triggering only affects your pipeline when 'shuffles' happen. A shuffle is done on a GBK, or before a stateful ParDo. Can you try adding a GroupByKey? - I believe that in your case, the timestamp combiner will determine the timestamp for the KV<K, Iterable<V>> that comes out of your GBK (and it will not discard older elements) - but after GBK you can discard the older elements yourself

Comment: why are you setting timers to 150 seconds but using 5 minutes in the window? to be sure to have output?

Comment: Exactly, I was setting the timers so that I was guaranteed to see at least one element per window.

I tried adding a groupByKey after the statefulDofn but it seems that not all of the flushed keys are now added to the output for some reason...

```scala
.withGlobalWindow()
  .applyPerKeyDoFn(stateFn)
  .groupByKey
    .withFixedWindows(...
```

Comment: In fact adding the groupByKey seems to prevent output every 5 minutes...

Comment: hmm what I would say is that windows are implemented using timers. You should be able to set your timers at once-per-window, and get the same result. Do you think that would work?

Comment: Yes I think that would work, that's probably the best option for the time being. The only problem is that I expect to run this job with live data which will inevitably output multiple values for a single key within a given window. I would somehow need to only output each key once every 5 minutes, which I suppose I could accomplish with a `lastEmittedTimestamp` or something similar, but this might not output the most recent version of a value... I'll update my code above to let others know what has worked so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that Stateful DoFn should help you here. This is a basic sketch of what you can do. Note that this only outputs the sum without the key. It may not be exactly what you want, but it should help you move forward.

```java
class CombiningEmittingFn extends DoFn<KV<Integer, Integer>, Integer> {

  @TimerId("emitter")
  private final TimerSpec emitterSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);

  @StateId("done")
  private final StateSpec<ValueState<Boolean>> doneState = StateSpecs.value();

  @StateId("agg")
  private final StateSpec<CombiningState<Integer, int[], Integer>>
      aggSpec = StateSpecs.combining(
          Sum.ofIntegers().getAccumulatorCoder(null, VarIntCoder.of()), Sum.ofIntegers());

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c,
      @StateId("agg") CombiningState<Integer, int[], Integer> aggState,
      @StateId("done") ValueState<Boolean> doneState,
      @TimerId("emitter") Timer emitterTimer) throws Exception {
        if (SOME CONDITION) {
          countValueState.clear();
          doneState.write(true);
        } else {
          countValueState.addAccum(c.element().getValue());
          emitterTimer.align(Duration.standardMinutes(5)).setRelative();
        }
      }
    }

  @OnTimer("emitter")
  public void onEmit(
      OnTimerContext context,
      @StateId("agg") CombiningState<Integer, int[], Integer> aggState,
      @StateId("done") ValueState<Boolean> doneState,
      @TimerId("emitter") Timer emitterTimer) {
      Boolean isDone = doneState.read();
      if (isDone != null && isDone) {
        return;
      } else {
        context.output(aggState.getAccum());
        // Set the timer to emit again
        emitterTimer.align(Duration.standardMinutes(5)).setRelative();
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

Happy to iterate with you on something that'll work.

Comment: Thanks much @pablo! I posted some code snippets above (seems very similar to your suggestion) but can't seem to get output to flush correctly.

Two differences I'm noticing are the TimerSpec you suggested is using PROCESSING_TIME rather than EVENT_TIME. Additionally, you suggested a CombiningState. Do you think these would have enough of an effect to cause the issues I'm seeing?

Answer (score 0):

@Pablo was indeed correct that a StatefulDoFn and timers are useful in this scenario. Here is the with code I was able to get working.

Stateful Do Fn

```scala
// DomainState is a custom case class I'm using
type DoFnT = DoFn[KV[String, DomainState], KV[String, DomainState]]

class StatefulDoFn extends DoFnT {

  @StateId("key")
  private val keySpec = StateSpecs.value[String]()

  @StateId("domainState")
  private val domainStateSpec = StateSpecs.value[DomainState]()

  @TimerId("loopingTimer")
  private val loopingTimer: TimerSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME)

  @ProcessElement
  def process(
      context: DoFnT#ProcessContext,
      @StateId("key") stateKey: ValueState[String],
      @StateId("domainState") stateValue: ValueState[DomainState],
      @TimerId("loopingTimer") loopingTimer: Timer): Unit = {

    ... logic to create key/value from potentially null values

    if (keepState(value)) {
      loopingTimer.align(Duration.standardMinutes(5)).setRelative()

      stateKey.write(key)
      stateValue.write(value)

      if (flushState(value)) {
        context.output(KV.of(key, value))
      }
    } else {
      stateValue.clear()
    }
  }

  @OnTimer("loopingTimer")
  def onLoopingTimer(
      context: DoFnT#OnTimerContext,
      @StateId("key") stateKey: ValueState[String],
      @StateId("domainState") stateValue: ValueState[DomainState],
      @TimerId("loopingTimer") loopingTimer: Timer): Unit = {

    ... logic to create key/value checking for nulls

    if (keepState(value)) {

      loopingTimer.align(Duration.standardMinutes(5)).setRelative()

      if (flushState(value)) {
        context.output(KV.of(key, value))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With pipeline

```scala
sc
  .pubsubSubscription(...)
  .keyBy(...)
  .withGlobalWindow()
  .applyPerKeyDoFn(new StatefulDoFn())
  .withFixedWindows(
    duration = Duration.standardMinutes(5),
    options = WindowOptions(
      accumulationMode = DISCARDING_FIRED_PANES,
      trigger = AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow(),
      allowedLateness = Duration.ZERO,
      // Only take the latest per key during a window
      timestampCombiner = TimestampCombiner.END_OF_WINDOW
    ))
  .reduceByKey(mostRecentEvent())
  .saveAsCustomOutput(TextIO.write()...)
```